# Laravel Queue Not Working on Hosted Server

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, redis, queue

I am working on `Laravel 5.1` , using `redis` as my queue driver everything working fine on my local server. But after pushing the code to my hosted server `mail::queue` works same as `mail::send`.

P.S. Redis is installed properly on the hosted server.

Comment: did you check the .env file on hosted server?

Comment: Are you running your queue worker (and does the hosting allow you to run background processes?)

Comment: Yes i did, it was redis configuration issue....thanks for the efforts...